# Solving the harmonic oscillator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

so this is a bit of physics but the question is math related. For a mass hanging on a spring we get the following differential equation:

$\ddot{z}+\frac{f}{m}\cdot z = \frac{m\cdot g + f\cdot z_0}{m}$ whereas

m: mass, f: constant of the spring, g: graviational constant, $z_0$: initial displacement

Now, I'd say that the homogenic solution is

$z_h(t)=A\cos(\sqrt{\frac{f}{m}}t-\varphi)$

Now, since our inhomogenity is constant, we can just say that:

$z_p(t)=\frac{m\cdot g + f\cdot z_0}{m}$

but my solution tells me, that we have:

$\frac{m\cdot g + f\cdot z_0}{f}$

I'm not sure if that's a typo or not. We would get that if we multiplied our initial differential equation with $\frac{m}{f}$ but I'm not sure why we'd do such a thing and I'm also not 100% sure about its implications.

Ah I think it makes sense... It just clicked. If we just "add" the inhomogenity to our solution, we would have to "norm" to respect the coefficient of out $z$ in our differential equation, no? In short: If we plut out solution into our differential equation, we should get the inhomogenity again.

Comment: With this constant  $z_p$ we have $z_p''=0$ then $$z =( \frac{m\cdot g + f\cdot z_0}{m}) / (\frac{f}{m})$$

Comment: You can get displayed equations by enclosing them in double instead of single dollar signs. Especially with fractions nested in roots and the like, that makes them a lot easier to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\ddot{z}+\frac{f}{m}\cdot z = \frac{m\cdot g + f\cdot z_0}{m}$$
$$\ddot{z}+\frac{f}{m}\cdot z - \frac{m\cdot g + f\cdot z_0}{m}=0$$
$$\ddot{z}+\frac{f}{m}\cdot( z - \frac mf \frac{m\cdot g + f\cdot z_0}{m})=0$$
$$\ddot{z}+\frac{f}{m}\left ( z - \frac {( m\cdot g + f\cdot z_0)}f\right)=0$$
it's equivalent to the homogeneous equation
$$v''+\frac fm v=0$$
Where
$$v=z - \frac {( m\cdot g + f\cdot z_0)}f$$
$$z =v+ \frac {( m\cdot g + f\cdot z_0)}f$$

Comment: the homogeneous solution to the equation @user108128  $$z_h=v$$